# VSCode IntelliSense does not show all exports from an namespace

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

in typescript when i create a namespace which holds also enums then only the exported enums are shown from intellisense

```
// file models.ts
namespace models {
  export enum Enum1 {
  }
  export interface Interface1 {    
  }
  export interface Interface2 {    
  }
}
```

now when i type models. in vscode it shows only Enum1
when i remove this enum then it shows both interfaces

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. Are you trying to get the suggestions in a value context or a type context? If you want to get suggestions for a type, then you should be triggering suggestions in a type context. Ex. `const a: models.` and then trigger suggestions.